# What database / technology should I use if I want to read the top N records sorted on some integer key?

Tags: sorting

What database / technology should I use if I want to read the top N records sorted on some integer key?

Currently, my data is stored using mongodb.

I don't have any limitations on technology except that they can't only run on windows.

Most popular / best documentation is preferred.

Comment: Any database that supports window functions!

Answer (score 1):

Please note this is a shopping list question so unfortunately it's off-topic here and you likely won't see much response.

---

"*Most popular / best documentation is preferred.*" - In that case, most likely one of the main relational database management systems are going to be your best bet, given they've been around so long and have the biggest followings.

I personally like Microsoft for their documentation and find it so easy to work with SQL Server because of the amount of information out there in addition to the documentation, between articles, blogs, and help forums. But PostgreSQL, MariaDB, and Oracle also all have good documentation and are popular enough that you can't go wrong with any of them either.

"*I want to read the top N records sorted on some integer key* - If this is your only use case, it's a very simple one, and any database system (I would assume even MongoDB) would be fairly equal in handling it from both a performance perspective and an amount of work from a management perspective.

Relational database management systems, such as the aforementioned examples, typically use B-Tree indexing which already stores the data sorted on the field(s) you specify, making lookups on the data in that order very fast. E.g. `SELECT TOP N FROM MyTable ORDER BY SomeIndexedIntegerKey` would be extremely fast.

---

As a side note (since you mentioned you're already using MongoDB), the main reasons to choose a NoSQL database system such as MongoDB over a relational database management system (SQL) should be based on if you need a flexible schema. Flexible schemas are useful when the structure of your data changes so frequently that you find it more beneficial to not manage the changes in the database layer, rather only at the consuming application layer. If you're not concerned about having to frequently manage a changing schema, then you likely have no specific constraints requiring you to stick to a NoSQL solution like MongoDB.